# Operator confusion when writing trigonometric expression in $k\sin(x-\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

If I want to rewrite the following 2 expressions in the form $k\sin(x-\alpha)$

a) $4\cos x - 3\sin x$

b) $\cos x + \sin x$

I am confused what happens to the operator in each case.

In case a

$4\cos x - 3\sin x = k\cos \alpha \sin x - k\sin \alpha \cos x$

$k\cos\alpha = -3$

$k\sin \alpha = -4$

In case b, I would say

$k\cos\alpha = 1$

$k\sin \alpha = 1$

I am confused how the operator works with the expression e.g. $\cos x + \sin x$ and the form $k\sin(x-\alpha)$.

Can anybody clarify how this works or why in case a, $k\cos\alpha = -(-3) = 3$ is not the outcome?

Comment: $k\cos \alpha \sin x - k\sin \alpha \cos x=k \sin(x-\alpha)$ is a trigonometric identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition theorem is
$$
\sin ( x \pm y ) = \sin x \; \cos y \pm \cos x \; \sin y \quad (*)
$$
which is a shorthand notation for the two variants
$$
\sin ( x + y ) = \sin x \; \cos y + \cos x \; \sin y \quad (**) \\
\sin ( x - y ) = \sin x \; \cos y - \cos x \; \sin y \quad (***)
$$
so
$$
k \sin(x - \alpha) = k (\sin(x) \cos(\alpha) - \cos(x) \sin(\alpha)) \\
$$
then for the first task we compare
$$
4 \cos(x) - 3 \sin(x) = k \sin(x - \alpha) = k \sin(x) \cos(\alpha) - k \cos(x) \sin(\alpha)
\Rightarrow \\
4 = -k \sin(\alpha) \\ 
-3 = k \cos(\alpha)
$$
or
$$
\cos(\alpha) = - \frac{3}{k} \\
\sin(\alpha) = - \frac{4}{k}
$$
We think of the famous triangle with $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$ and
come up with $k = 5$.

[image: cosine and sine]
[image: 3 4 5 trriangle]

To get both negative sine and cosine the angle is beyond $\pi$ and from the triangle we take $\tan(\alpha-\pi) = 4/3$ or $\alpha = 180^\circ + 53.13^\circ = 233.13^\circ = 4.07$.

This gives
$$
4 \cos(x) - 3 \sin(x) = 5 \sin(x - 4.07)
$$

For the second task we compare
$$
\cos(x) + \sin(x) = k \sin(x - \alpha) = k \sin(x) \cos(\alpha) - k \cos(x) \sin(\alpha)
\Rightarrow \\
1 = -k \sin(\alpha) \\ 
1 = k \cos(\alpha)
$$
or
$$
\cos(\alpha) = \frac{1}{k} \\
\sin(\alpha) = -\frac{1}{k}
$$
Here the right angled triangle with sides $1^2 + 1^2 = \sqrt{2}^2$ helps.
We get $k = \sqrt{2}$ 
and the signs of cosine and sine are correct for angles beyond $3\pi/2$, 
so we have
$\tan(\alpha - 3\pi/2) = 1$ or $\alpha = 3\pi/2 + \pi/4 = 270^\circ + 45^\circ = 315^\circ$. 
This gives
$$
\cos(x) + \sin(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin(x - 315^\circ)
$$

Comment: The answer in the book for $\cos x + \sin x$ is $y = \sqrt{2}\sin (x - 315)^{\circ}$ which would suggest that $\sin$ is negative and mean the angle is in the 4th quarter.  Are you saying both cos and sin are positiive?  If so how is the answer acheieved

Comment: That is the same solution. $\sin(x + \pi/4) = \sin(x + 45^\circ) = \sin(x + 45^\circ - 360^\circ) = \sin(x - 315^\circ)$, due to the $360^\circ$ periodicity of the sine function. But I have changed the answer because it seems you prefer that way (using the "-" variant of the theorem $(*)$ instead the "+" variant).

Comment: why is sine negative,  where is that coming from and why did you have it originally positive.  I am confused if can be both

Comment: It depends on what variant of $(*)$ one uses: For the second task I first used the $(**)$ variant of $(*)$, that required both cosine and sine to be positive and came up with the answer featuring $\sin(x + 45^\circ)$. Then came your question and I changed it to use the $(***)$ variant of $(*)$, which gave $\sin(x - 315^\circ)$. Both are the same solutions (see my comment), just written once in a form depending on $x + \alpha$ and the other as $x - \alpha$. If one uses the $(***)$ variant, then the comparison is $\cos(x)$ vs $-k \cos(x) \sin(\alpha)$ or in other words $1 = -k \sin(\alpha)$.

Comment: ok great, I'll try and digest all this.  this is without doubt the most confusing thing I have encountered in maths so far

Comment: It is deciding to use $(***)$, then looking what signs the cosine and sine must have (use the left image with the plot).